# Weights for patternent labels

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to introduce weights for my training instances in neural network toolbox in Matlab. Am I doing everything correctly? I have to ask because as far as I can see, NN toolbox documentation can suite only very basic needs. Everything else is not that straightforward.

So I create neural network as follows:

```
net = patternnet([5,5])
```

Let's also say, my network has 4 possible outputs(or 4 possible classes in my classification problem, if you want). This is **train** function signature:

```
[net,tr] = train(net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW)
```

Here **EW** represents error weights as it stated in documentation. As far as I understood from reading docs and some articles in the web, I have to have **EW** in a form of a cell array that has the same dimensions as my labels array?

Imagine that my labels array is **[N 4]** matrix, where `N` is a number of training examples. So,the question is: am I doing correctly if I want to introduce equal weights for all instances?

```
EW = ones(size(labels));
EW = num2cell(EW);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I guess I've found a way how to do it.

It is all the same as I described, but **EW** should be

```
EW = num2cell(ones([length(labels) 1]));
```

Therefore, we will have once weight per instance. However, for some reason the code I've posted in my question body is working as well, but training results give nothing but non-working NN.

I'll be very glad if you have any notes and additions. 
Thank you.